# How can I apply a transition onto a list element and make it grow without affecting its background image or the other list items?

Tags: html, css, css-transitions, nav

I'm working on a flat design website and lately I've been focusing on the navbar. Traditionally, I wanted to use simple icons on top of a colored background that would get darker when the user's mouse hovered over it. So I got that done by using the list item background as the color and the "anchor" item for the pictures. But then I wanted it to have a little more interactivity. So I decided that I wanted the list item to grow while keeping the simple icon the same size and not affecting the placement of the other list items. So far, I've gotten the list item to grow and stay in place, but the background gets distorted and the rest of the list items move downwards when the list item is hovered over. This is my CSS:

```
div#nav{
    width:auto;
    height:43px;
    padding-top:15px;
    padding-right:15px;
    padding-bottom:5px;
    background-color:rgba(100,100,100,0.2);
    border-left-color:rgba(255,255,255,0.2);
    border-right-color:rgba(255,255,255,0.2);
    border-right-width:1px;
    border-right-style:solid;
    border-left-width:1px;
    border-left-style:solid;
    border-top-width:1px;
    border-top-style:solid;
    border-top-color:rgba(255,255,255,0.2);
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
}
#nav ul{
    padding:0;
    list-style:none;
    display:inline-block;
    margin:0;
}
#nav ul li{
    width:48px;
    height:48px;
    margin-left:15px;
    display:inline-block;
    background-color:#000000;
    padding:0;
}
#nav ul li a{
    z-index:10;
}
#googleplus{
    width:48px;
    height:48px;
    background-image:url('images/googleplus.png');
    display:block;
}
#facebook{
    width:48px;
    height:48px;
    background-image:url('images/facebook.png');
    display:block;
}
#twitter{
    width:48px;
    height:48px;
    background-image:url('images/twitter.png');
    display:block;
}
#youtube{
    width:48px;
    height:48px;
    background-image:url('images/youtube.png');
    display:block;
}
#minecraft{
    width:48px;
    height:48px;
    background-image:url('images/minecraft.png');
    display:block;
}
#nav ul li#googleplus{
    background-color:#d34836;
    transition:background-color;
    transition-duration:0.17s;
}
#nav ul li#googleplus:hover{
    background-color:#c23725;
}
#nav ul li#facebook{
    background-color:#3b5998;
    transition:background-color,padding,margin-left,margin-right,margin-top,margin-bottom;
    transition-duration:0.17s,0.17s,0.17s,0.17s,0.17s,0.17s;
}
#nav ul li#facebook:hover{
    background-color:#2a4887;
    padding:5px;
    margin-left:10px;
    margin-right:-5px;
    margin-top:-5px;
    margin-bottom:5px;
}
#nav ul li#twitter{
    background-color:#4099ff;
    transition:background-color;
    transition-duration:0.17s;
}
#nav ul li#twitter:hover{
    background-color:#2077dd;
}
#nav ul li#youtube{
    background-color:#de443e;
    transition:background-color;
    transition-duration:0.17s;
}
#nav ul li#youtube:hover{
    background-color:#bc221c;
}
#nav ul li#minecraft{
    background-color:#5e5645;
    transition:background-color;
    transition-duration:0.17s;
}
#nav ul li#minecraft:hover{
    background-color:#4d4534;
}
.p-flexbox{
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -moz-box;
    display: box;
}
.flex-hcc{
    -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
    -moz-box-orient: horizontal;
    box-orient: horizontal;

    -webkit-box-pack: center;
    -moz-box-pack: center;
    box-pack: center;

    -webkit-box-align: center;
    -moz-box-align: center;
    box-align: center;
}
```

And this is the HTML:

```
<div id="nav" class="p-flexbox flex-hcc">
    <ul>
        <li id="facebook" ><a id="facebook" href="#" ></a></li>
        <li id="twitter" ><a id="twitter" href="#" ></a></li>
        <li id="youtube" ><a id="youtube" href="#" ></a></li>
        <li id="minecraft" ><a id="minecraft" href="#" ></a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Can anyone figure out a way to make the list item grow, but keep the background image to the anchor stay in the same place and size, as well as not affect the placement of the other list items?

Comment: Your question is a bit confusing. If you put this into a JSfiddle, we would have better understanding of what you're running into.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/PfdFe/

Comment: I'll add in all the code just to get a better view of a few extra issues I didn't address, like the discoloring at the bottom of the list items when they are both expanded and moved.

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to reduce the margin top value and the margin bottom value on the #facebook:hover css rule:

```
#nav ul li#facebook:hover{
    background-color:#2a4887;
    padding:5px;
    margin-left:10px;
    margin-right:-5px;
    margin-top:-15px;
    margin-bottom:0px;
}
```

See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jessekinsman/wgLWT/3/

Not sure if this is what you were trying to get at though. They are lining up at the bottom and the other elements are not moving.